# jQuery does not get the checked input when it is set true before the others are set false

Tags: jquery, radio-button, undefined, selected

I saw an interesting behavior of jQuery , and I dont know why, its not really a problem now, because I "fixed" it, but I want to share this with you, look at the code:

```
            switch(id){
            case "1k":
                check5k.attr('checked', false);
                check10k.attr('checked', false);
                check1k.attr('checked', true);
                image1k.attr('class', 'radio-checked1k');
                image5k.attr('class', 'radio5k');
                image10k.attr('class', 'radio10k');
                break;
            case "5k":
                check1k.attr('checked', false);
                check10k.attr('checked', false);
                check5k.attr('checked', true);
                image1k.attr('class', 'radio1k');
                image5k.attr('class', 'radio-checked5k');
                image10k.attr('class', 'radio10k');
                break;
            case "10k":
                check1k.attr('checked', false);
                check5k.attr('checked', false);
                check10k.attr('checked', true);
                image1k.attr('class', 'radio1k');
                image5k.attr('class', 'radio5k');
                image10k.attr('class', 'radio-checked10k');
                break;
        }
```

So, it works , when I try to `alert($("input:checked").val())`, it shows me the current selected radio value, but, if I do like this:

```
            switch(id){
            case "1k":
                check1k.attr('checked', true);
                check5k.attr('checked', false);
                check10k.attr('checked', false);
                image1k.attr('class', 'radio-checked1k');
                image5k.attr('class', 'radio5k');
                image10k.attr('class', 'radio10k');
                break;
            case "5k":
                check1k.attr('checked', false);
                check5k.attr('checked', true);
                check10k.attr('checked', false);
                image1k.attr('class', 'radio1k');
                image5k.attr('class', 'radio-checked5k');
                image10k.attr('class', 'radio10k');
                break;
            case "10k":
                check1k.attr('checked', false);
                check5k.attr('checked', false);
                check10k.attr('checked', true);
                image1k.attr('class', 'radio1k');
                image5k.attr('class', 'radio5k');
                image10k.attr('class', 'radio-checked10k');
                break;
        }
```

And try to make the same `alert($("input:checked").val())` it shows the value only for the 10k id, the others are shown undefined. The 10k shows the value because it was the last one that what is set true in this case.

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the checked attribute wrong. In jQuery you do `.attr('checked', 'checked')` to set it, and `.removeAttr('checked')` to unset it.*

*Before jQuery 1.6. After 1.6, you use [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: depending on the version of jQuery yes ... but since 1.6 if you use .attr() you will get `checked` and with .prop() you will get `true`